# How to setup IntelliJ IDEA 14 to add "final" keyword where possible?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, final, intellij-14

I would like to setup my IntelliJ IDEA 14 for automatic `final` keyword adding in all possible places (parameters, fields, etc.) to the existing Java class. I found some solutions with macros and shortcuts but I would like setup IntelliJ to add the `final` keyword when it saves the file. Does anyone know a good solution for this? Maybe can you recommend some plugin or combination of plugins?

Comment: I would not recommend even trying this. Just because it is currently possible, doesn't mean it is supposed to be so. Meaning, you'll probably spend quite some time afterwards solving ye olde 'trying to re-reference final variable' errors.

Comment: @Stultuske, I'm just asking whether (and how) it is possible to setup this functionality on save. As far as remember Eclipse has similar functionality on save and I'm searching same functionality in IntelliJ.

Comment: Disagree with @Stultuske - I strongly believe it's better to favor immutability over mutability. Especially in a team/corporate environment, it's much better and safer to know when you are choosing mutability than to have variables left mutable when you aren't expecting that behavior.

Answer (score 30):

## Preferences - Code style issues

Since the [2018.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137056) version we can enable the checkbox:

`Preferences/Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Code style issues > Local variable or parameter can be final`

Then perform the reformat code action.

If the [Code cleanup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/reformat-file-dialog.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2020.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product) checkbox is enabled then IDEA will automatically add final where possible.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ 2021.1 > Preferences/Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Code style issues > Local variable or parameter can be final]

Answer (score 14):

Open the "Configure inspections" view (click on the person in the hat icon).  Search on "final" and you'll find various options in the code style section that you can enable to enable highlighting of candidates for `final`.  You can then use alt-return to apply the suggestion within a given file.

I wouldn't recommend you do it automatically on saving!

Comment: I'm just asking whether (and how) it is possible to setup this functionality on save. As far as remember Eclipse has similar functionality on save and I'm searching same functionality in IntelliJ.

Comment: He was asking for how to do it, not whether you agree w/ him or not.

Answer (score 10):

Use `Save Actions` plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions

You can enable adding of `final` keywords in:

Settings -> Other Settings -> Save Actions -> Add final to field/local variable`.